# is there kustomize version used by flux kustomization

Tags: flux, kustomize

I'm new in flux, I wonder what kind of kustomize version used by flux kustomization to do the build? where I can find this information? or I'm totally wrong, there is no such thing? thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered in github discussion: https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2/discussions/4518

Comment: this is not a solution, but a comment.